# How this std::string pointer turns into array?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers, stdstring

Hi I am having trouble with this code here from a tutorial about returning Arrays from functions

```
std::string(&func(std::string(&arr)[10]))[10]
{
    return arr;
}

int main()
{
   std::string array[10] = { "efwefwef","wefffj","mfls","hrkr","sgte","ege","ky","retg","sujtre","fl;yiu" };

   std::string* array23 = func(array);
   std::cout << array23[0] << std::endl; // why does this work
   std::cout << array23[1] << std::endl; // why does this work
}
```

It compiles fine but I am confused as to how `std::string* array23` can be used with the index operator.

I initially thought that this was because `std::string` was an array of characters and you could access them individually with the index operator but this next code works and I can not figure out why.

```
::std::uintptr_t x = 2453;
::std::uintptr_t* pX = &x;
std::cout << "Var: " << pX[0]; // pX prints 2453
```

Comment: In absence of operator overloading, `a[b]` is equivalent to `*(a+b)`. Also I'm not sure what `func` is for, you could write `std::string *array32 = array;` directly. And if a tutorial uses convoluted declarations like `std::string(&func(std::string(&arr)[10]))[10]` for any purpose other than teaching you how to read them, it's probably not the best tutorial.

Comment: I have no idea what this code does; that declaration is far too complicated for pretty much anyone to read. Use `typedef` to create names for intermediate types and use those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The plane arrays(c-style) can be decayed to a pointer to the type of the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay), and the pointee can be accessed using `operator[]` (i.e pointer[index]).

---

The function `func` returns the reference to an (c-style) array of `std::string`s with `10` elements in it.

If you write the function clearly with an alias, it would look like:

```
// alias type: the returned type!
using Type = std::string(&)[10];

Type func(std::string (&arr)[10])
{
    return arr;
}
```

The `std::string(&)[10]` array elements can be accessed like normal c-style array via `operator[]`. So the question is why the code you showed works (i.e. `std::string* array23`)?

This because of the reason mentioned above. In the case of

```
std::string* array23 = func(array);
```

The returned (c-style) array(i.e. from `func(array);`) is decay to the pointer pointing to the first element of the array.

Meaning

```
array23[0]
```

is equivalent to

```
*(array23 + 0)
```

and hence it works! The same applies to `array23[1]` (i.e. equalent to  `*(array23 + 1)`).

---

If you write the actual type instead there, you need

```
std::string (&array23)[10] = func(array);
// or
// Type array23 = func(array);
```

Comment: *"func returns the reference to an array ... meaning ... `std::string* array23` ... is equivalent to ... `std::string (&array23)[10]` ... therefore ... `operator[]` ... works"* I feel this is very very misleading. The two are not equivalent. And `[]` working has nothing to do with `func` returning a reference.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes, realized after wrote the answer. Updated the answer as per. Thanks for pointing out. It should be clear now.